# OnClickListener crashing application

Tags: android, button, onclick

The following code is crashing my application on startup.
It compiles just fine but just crashes.
Without this code it runs perfectly.

This is the code

```
private OnClickListener listentest = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button teamsbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.teams);
  //  teamsbtn.setOnClickListener(listentest); 
     }
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace from the crash.  Use logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  It could be something to do with "when" the OnClickListener is created in the overall app lifecycle, with regard to parent class in particular.  I haven't personally tried it like this.

What if you instead make a class which you instantiate during the onCreate ?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listentest = new MyOnClickListener();

    Button teamsbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.teams);

    teamsbtn.setOnClickListener(listentest); 
 }



private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};
```

Comment: 3 years late, but shouldn't `private MyOnClickListener` be `private class MyOnClickListener`?